# Manwha where the female lead uses a spell/magic circle to escape being killed by her sister

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, magic

Can anyone please help me find the manwha (Korean comic) where the female lead was imprisoned by her sister because she wanted to steal the male lead?

The sister told FL that ML did not love her and had her imprisoned (it was a lie) while male lead was outside the palace.

Crucial point of the story is the female lead is able to get back to the original timeline by drawing a magic circle on the dress she wore when she escaped from the prison.

It turns out, the emperor had her dress displayed in his bedroom because he could not get over her. She ends up teleporting to ML's (emperor's) bedroom and the emperor wakes up and couldn't believe she's alive. She becomes scared and runs back to her dress to teleport back to her timeline. The emperor tries to chase her but fails and his servants rush into the room to find out what's happening and to protect the emperor.

Edit: I think the FL hair color is red but I know the emperor's hair is black

Comment: You seem to have created a new account here which is different from your original account. Please consider following [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts so that you can regain access to the original account.